# Java/Demorgan's Law/Boolean Algebra/Random Dice/

Tags: java, random, static, demorgans-law, boolean-algebra

I need some help getting this code to work.

I need to be able to Write a program that counts how many times three six-sided dice must be rolled until the values showing are all different.

**Instructions:**

Write a driver that generates 10 output runs.

Here is an example of two output runs.

```
2 6 5

count = 1

5 3 5

3 5 3

3 3 4

1 3 3

2 5 4

count = 5
```

Here is my code so far, I don't exactly know where and how to apply DeMorgan's law to this.

```
import java.util.Random;
 public class P4_Icel_Murad_Rolling
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        P4_Icel_Murad_Rolling obj = new P4_Icel_Murad_Rolling();
        obj.rolling(10);
    }

    public void rolling(int number){
        int counter = 0;
        Random num = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
          int A = num.nextInt(6);
          System.out.print(A + " ");
          int B = num.nextInt(6); 
          System.out.print(B + " ");
          int C = num.nextInt(6); 
          System.out.print(C + " ");
          if((){
            counter++;
            }
          System.out.println();
        }        
    }


}
```

Comment: why you need to apply de'morgen's low here ?

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge it's a part of the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
(I don't know hot to apply de Morgan's Laws here.)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  P4_Icel_Murad_Rolling obj = new P4_Icel_Murad_Rolling();
  obj.rolling(10);
}

public void rolling(int number){
  int counter = 1;
  Random num = new Random();
  for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {

    int A = num.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.print(A + " ");

    int B = num.nextInt(6) + 1; 
    System.out.print(B + " ");

    int C = num.nextInt(6) + 1; 
    System.out.print(C + "\n");

    if(A == B || A == C || B == C) {
      counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("count = " + counter);
  }        
}
```